How to ignore mapping null properties in Auto Mapper globally
I am using .Net 8 and I want to know how to ignore mapping null properties globally in Auto Mapper
I know that I can use
ForAllMembers(opts =>
        {
            // Skip null source values during mapping
            opts.Condition((source, destination, sourceMember, destMember) => sourceMember != null);
        });

but I want to do that globally not for every single mapping profile
I have tried using
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ForAllMaps((map, exp) =>
    {
        exp.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
    });
}, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

and
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(
        pm => pm.SourceType != null,
        (pm, exp) => exp.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null)
    );
}, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

but it appears that ForAllMaps is not defined in the version I am using or something
